# Take the first 100 characters from content MVC 5 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp MVC 5 with entity framework 6.1 code first.
I made a view for the articles.

I want to take only the first 100 characters from the content to put it in the index view. How can I do it ?

```
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
</td>
```

Comment: @StephenKennedy I think his confusion is caused by the use of `DisplayFor`. If you were to try to call `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Content.Substring(0, 100))` it wouldn't work, because `DisplayFor` is using an `Expression` to get attributes off of the property being referenced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skip the `Html.DisplayFor` and just render the substring directly.

```
<td>@item.Content.Substring(0, 100)</td>
```

The rendering engine (assumed to be Razor) will properly escape your string for you.

The reason your attempt with [`DisplayFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390(v=vs.118).aspx) was not working is that, if you try to use `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Content.Substring(0, 100))`, the `Expression<Func<TModel, string>>` being passed to `DisplayFor` becomes too complex for it to use. `DisplayFor` expects a simple property access, not an arbitrary expression.

Comment: Thank you it is worked with me. I was trying to add it without skipping the DisplayFor

Comment: Tried that and BOOM! "location within the string" error because some were < 100.  Had to go with item.Content.Substring(0,Math.Min(item.Content.Length, 100))

Answer (score 2):

I guess you use it in a `@foreach` loop, so..

`.Substring()` method is the way but if your `item.Content` character count turns less than 100, your view will be boom.

You need to check it before taking first 100 character. Try this:

```
    @if (item.Content.Length >= 100)
    {
        @item.Content.Substring(0, 100)
        <text> ... </text>
    }
    else
    {
        @item.Content
    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect, even though index starts at 0 you still want 100 characters and the second parameter for substring method is the specified length, if you were doing a loop then 0 to 99 would be valid.